# TypeScript Strict in Visual Studio Code Problems Panel

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've figured out that I can compile my TypeScript using the `--strict` flag which enforces stronger type checking etc. I often compile my TypeScript from within Visual Studio Code by using a task that gives me the output of the compile in the Output panel so I can see compilation errors, etc (see screenshot below).

However, even though Visual Studio Code seems to perform "pre-compilation" of the TypeScript and reports basic syntax errors (etc) in the Problems panel, the **strict** results never appear there. (Note that my main project is C# ASP.NET with a TypeScript component).

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio Code to pre-compile TypeScript using the `--strict` option so the errors appear in the Problems panel?

[image: Visual Studio Code showing TypeScript compilation errors]

Comment: What version of TypeScript is used by Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Very likely that VS Code is using 2.2.x and your task is executed using 2.3.x .

Comment: Good thinking, but according to the VSCode footer, it's using 2.3.1 and that version is "currently active." I feel like it's just not enforcing strict rules.

Comment: How are you specifying the `--strict` flag? Did you set it in `tsconfig.json` or just passed it as an argument to the build task?

Comment: @Saravana see below. It is now in the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup a [`tsconfig.json` file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) to tell VScode what your project looks like and what compiler options to use for error reporting. Just create a `tsconfig.json` at the root of your workspace with the content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

You would then compile your project using `tsc -p tsconfig.json` instead of passing the the `--strict` flag

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I'm not able to get that to work. It's possibly because my project was set up as ASP.NET and the TypeScript component is "peripheral" to the project. Maybe I just need to live with it.

Comment: If you share your project setup, I may be able to provide a better example config. Also try looking into the `"files" and `"include"`` options for the tsconfig: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Aha. I am new to TypeScript and I'd forgotten I already had a tsconfig.json and I was already using the tsc -p tsconfig.json method. Adding strict to the json file is cleaner and I have done that and things are working generally well... except I am still not noticing any strict output in the Problems panel. Strict output does show up in the Output panel, however...